# Import Unpivot results to new Table and match on Key

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-insert, unpivot

I currently have a few unpivot queries that yeilds about 2000 rows each. I need to take the results of those queires, and put in a new table to match on a key.

Query Example:

```
Select DeviceSlot
  FROM tbl1
  unpivot(
  DeviceSlot
  For col in(
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
  )
  )AS Unpivot
```

Now I need to match the results from the query, and insert it into a new table with about 20,000 rows. 
Pseudo-Code for this:

```
Insert Into tbl2(DeviceSlot)
  Select DeviceSlot
  FROM tbl1
  unpivot(
  DeviceSlot
  For col in(
       col1,
       col2,
       col3
  )
  )AS Unpivot2
  Where tbl1.key = tbl2.key
```

I've been pretty confused on how to do this, and I apologize if it is not clear.
I also have another unpivot query doing the same thing for different columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking for. While unpivoting to "normalize" data typically the wanted "key" is derived during the unpivot, for example, below the id column of the original table is repeated in the un-pivoted data to represent a foreign key for some new table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89160/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([id] int, [col1] varchar(2), [col2] varchar(2), [col3] varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
    (2, 'aa', 'bb', 'cc')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id as table1_fk, colheading, colvalue
from (
  select * from table1
  ) t
unpivot (
     colvalue for colheading in (col1, col2, col3) 
    ) u
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89160/1/0)**:

```
| table1_fk | colheading | colvalue |
|-----------|------------|----------|
|         1 |       col1 |        a |
|         1 |       col2 |        b |
|         1 |       col3 |        c |
|         2 |       col1 |       aa |
|         2 |       col2 |       bb |
|         2 |       col3 |       cc |
```